# How to get the number of open MDI children

Tags: c#, mdi, children

In C#, how do you obtain the number of open MDI children windows? I could make my own counter, but I'm not sure if there's already some in-built functionality for this.

I tried using `MdiChildren.Length` but this consistently returned `0` even though there were multiple MDI children open already.

Thanks.

Comment: MdiChildren.Length should be returning the number of items in the MdiChildren array, so this should work for you -- can you post some code?  You could also iterate through the MdiChildren collection yourself to count them up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your mdi container form `this.MdiChildren.Length` should return the correct count.

Comment: Ahh, I see. I was trying to do this in my child. Created a new method to call from the MDI container and now it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
int openFormCount = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>()
    .Count(openForm => openForm.IsMdiChild);
```